# All my @client.events work but not my @client.command, but if its just the command and the on_ready event, the @client.command works

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Here's my code. It's still in early development. Also, I'm fairly new to developing bots.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = discord.Client()
bot_prefix: str = ">"
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=bot_prefix)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Miska Rise')
```

Here's the one event I have right now:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return None

    if message.content.startswith('woof') or message.content.startswith('Woof'):
        await message.channel.send('Bork!')
```

Here's the command:

```
@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Pong!')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you override `on_message`, you need to call [`Bot.process_commands`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands) in it, so that commands are still processed.

See the [Why does `on_message` make my commands stop working? section of the FAQ in the documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working).